# How to get the exact screensize of an iPhone 6 or 6 Plus

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I am using cocoas2d-x V3.0. I tried

```
Size    screenSize = CCDirector::getInstance()->getWinSizeInPixels();
```

but it returns the size of an iPhone 5 (640 * 1136), while I am testing on iPhone 6 or iPhone 6plus simulator.

Comment: is it a new project created in xcode 6 or the old version on which you are trying to do compatibility with 6,6+ ?

Comment: v3.0 probably doesn't know about iPhone 6, try the latest version

Comment: @ismail yeah i created a new project in xcode 6.1.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D let me try v3.3. then i will tell you.thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get cocos2d-x v3.3 because the previous versions of cocos2d-x do not get the correct screen resolution for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus because they still think that the scale factor is 2 instead of 3 and hence return the iPhone 5 resolution.

This issue has been talked about at this link: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/8545

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add Launch images for Iphone 6 & 6+ , only then 
it will show you its real screen size.

Go to your Xcode -> Select Target -> Select General -> 
select Launch Image Source under App Icons & Launch Images . 

Now you can add there your launch images for iphone 6 & plus
which could be 1334*750 & 2208*1242 For landScape mode.

Now you can have your device screenSize with following code .

Size WinSize= Director::getInstance()->getWinSize(); 

i have faced same thing in my project & this way i solved it.
i am using Xcode 6 & cocos2d-x 3.2 

I hope this helps.
```